# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

`public ActionResult Index(int? Page)
        {
            var db = new Entiti();
            var _categories = db.Kategoris.OrderBy(p => p.KategoriSirasi).ToPagedList(Page ?? 1, 10);
            return View(_categories);
        }`

Hi ;

Doing the Create process.

What do you think is the reason for my not receive this error

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: Please don't link to an image of your error. Images are not searchable. Put the actual error text in your question. Look at the Text property and at the inner exception, if any. This is often but not always caused by a SQL  deadlock.

Comment: The other part of the message you have not posted is: "See the inner exception for more details"

Comment: wiew Detail InnerException : Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'./r/nIvalid usage of the option Next in the FETCH statement

Comment: Try just do little test, return the  _categories without set ToPagedList, or, try  var _categories = db.Kategoris.Select(s => s).OrderBy(o => o.KategoriSirasi).

If the problem persists, add the try catch block and try catch the inner exception.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your data variable in database, and in your code. Because some data are not compatible with the equal operator. I also faced this problem in my Project.In my code I am using equal operator. But in my database I'm am using Text variable type for. email and password. After this I face the problem like you. Then I change the email and password value to varchar(20), It already solve. Hope its OK bro

```
  var obj = db.sales.Where(a => a.email.Equals(objUser.email) && a.pass.Equals(objUser.pass)).FirstOrDefault();
```